# Проблема с шейдером

Tags: android, libgdx

подскажите пожалуйста, нарисовал эллипс, что внутренними отступами, теперь хочу на нем с помощью шейдера нарисовать диагональную линию, и проблема в том, что она появляется только тогда, когда камера смотрит на модель, если переместить ее, то пропадает,хочу, чтобы она постоянно была на модели, и ещё эллипс крутится вокруг своей оси, и линия стоит на месте , подскажите, в чем проблема ?
Вот код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте в качестве st(текстурных координат) использовать varying v_texCoord, которую Вы устанавливаете в вершинном шейдере

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за подсказку, попробую